# Split up an int array into 3 parts, maximize the size of the 2 smaller parts

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given an `int` array of length `n`, split up the array into 3 parts and make sure that the 2 smaller parts are as large as possible.

Splitting rules:

- pick two indices `a` and `b` of the given array (0 <= a <= b <= n-1)
- Size of first part is: sum of all array entries from index 0 to a-1 (inclusive)
- Size of second part is: sum of all array entries from index a to b (inclusive)
- Size of third part is: sum of all array entries from b+1 to n-1 (inclusive)
- empty parts are possible..

The expected output is the sum of the 2 smaller parts (their sizes).

Example, an array of`n = 6` and some values are given.
The solution calculates `a = 2`, `b = 3` which splits the array into 3 parts: left part is of size `6 + 7 = 13`, middle part is `8 + 9 = 17`, right part is `4 + 5 = 9`. Output is `13 + 9 = 22` (sum of the 2 smaller parts).

Graphical representation:

[image: Graphical representation of a wanted array split]

More examples:

[6, 8,  3, 5, 7,  2, 4, 6] should be split up into:

1. Left (`6 + 8 = 14`)
2. Middle (`3 + 5 + 7 = 15`)
3. Right (`2 + 4 + 6 = 12`)

Output is `14 + 12 = 26` (sum of the 2 smaller parts)

[9, 12, 4,  7, 10, 2, 5, 8, 11, 3] should be split up into:

1. Left (`9 +  12 + 4 = 25`)
2. Middle (`7 + 10 + 2 + 5 = 24`)
3. Right (`8 + 11 + 3 = 22`)

Output is `22 + 24 = 46` (sum of the 2 smaller parts)

My approach doesn't work for the given test cases:

```
// L is size of left part, M is size of middle part, R is size of right part
/* I start with all array entries in the middle part, then I put elements 
   out of the middle part into the left and right part (depending on which 
   is smaller) until one of them is larger than M, this approach works for 
   many cases, two exceptions are the first 2 arrays given as examples in 
   this post. 
*/
       long a = 1;
       long b = n;
       long L = R = 0;
       long M = arr.sumOfAllArrayEntries;
       long temp;
       long[] arr = {9, 12, 4,  7, 10, 2, 5, 8, 11, 3}; 

       while (M > Math.max(L, R)) {
            if (L < R) {
                // move leftmost element of M to L
                temp = arr[(int) a++];

                M -= temp;
                L += temp;

            }
            else {
                // move rightmost element of M to R
                temp = arr[(int) b--];

                M -= temp;
                R += temp;
            }
        }

        // finds maximum of M, L, R 
        temp = Math.max(M, Math.max(L, R));

        // finds 2 smallest numbers out of M, L, R 
        if (temp == M)
            temp = L + R;
        else if (temp == L)
            temp = M + R;
        else if (temp == R)
            temp = M + L;

        // temp is equal to the sum of the 2 smaller parts
        System.out.println("Output: " + temp);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea that comes to mind:

- Loop over all positions for `a`.

  - Loop over all positions for `b`.

    - Calculate the left, mid and right sum.
    - Calculate the target sum and store this if it's better than the best sum we've seen.

This can be optimised to `O(n)` by noting a few things:

- For any given position `b`, the best position for `a` will always be, sum-wise, in the middle of `b` and the start (specifically at the point that minimises the difference between the left and mid sums).
- The best position for `a` can't move left as `b` moves right (since that will decrease left sum for a bigger mid sum, decreasing the target sum).
- This means we only need one loop over `b`, while keeping track of `a` as we go, increasing it when appropriate.
- We can keep track of the sums as we go.

This gives us the following code:

```
int arr[] = {9, 12, 4, 7, 10, 2, 5, 8, 11, 3};
int sum = 0;
for (int i: arr)
    sum += i;
int a = 0;
int left = 0, mid = 0;
int best = 0;
for (int b = 0; b < arr.length; b++)
{
    mid += arr[b];
    // since this loop increases `a` with every iteration,  and `a` never resets,
    // it will not run more than O(n) times in total
    while (a < b && Math.min(left + arr[a], mid - arr[a]) > Math.min(left, mid))
    {
        left += arr[a];
        mid -= arr[a];
        a++;
    }
    int right = sum - mid - left;
    best = Math.max(best,
                    mid + left + right - Math.max(mid, Math.max(left, right)));
}
System.out.println(best);
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/o3L9ik).

---

The problem with your approach is when you get into a situation like:

```
     a      b
6  7 | 8  9 | 4  5
L=13   M=17   R=9
```

`M > Math.max(L, R)` will be true, so you'll move one of the elements, despite already having the best split.

Note how I did `Math.min(left + arr[a], mid - arr[a]) > Math.min(left, mid)` in my code instead of simply `left < mid`. You will need something similar to check whether you should continue.

An example you'd need to consider is one where you need to further increase the bigger side:

```
100 | 10 120 | 90 -> 100 10 | 120 | 90
```

That might complicate your code quite a bit more.

Comment: Try [4, 3, 2, 9, 8], output should be 17 (the split is 4+3+2=9, 9, 8). Your algorithm returns 15. Also the oldbest variable seems unnecessary. Interesting approach!

Comment: @AnnaVopureta Nice catch, edited - that should've been a while-loop instead of an if-statement. oldbest was just a debug variable I forgot about.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using concept of `Two Pointers`.So first see main array as concatenation of `3` sub-arrays. `A`,`B` and `C`. Now we can first calculate total sum of all elements of array which indicates the considered array has all the elements.

So now we need to keep track of summation of 3 continuous subarrays of the original array. Consider here that we have 3 arrays here as

```
A  ---> Starting from the left-side (index 0)
B  ---> Middle sub-array
C  ---> Starting from the right-side (index n-1)
```

Here answer should be `min(sumOfA,min(sumOfB,sumOfC))` which is to be maximized.

Here we have stored summation of all elements in sub-array `B` considering it has all elements of array. `A` and `C` are empty. Now we will remove one by one element from either of the end and add that value to appropriate sub-array `A` or `C` and we need to delete it from the `B` by subtracting it.

Now the question remains that which element is to be removed. For this we will check value of `A` and `C` and whoever has lower sum than other one, we will add elements from that end to the specific sub-array.

Another problem here may arise is Termination Condition. Here termination condition would be `Sum of B > Sum of A && Sum of B > Sum of C`. So when sum of `B` becomes lesser than any of the other two sub arrays, we need to stop there.

**Complexity of this approach : O(n)**

**Code :**

```
import java.util.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        long arr[]={9, 12, 4, 7, 10, 2, 5, 8, 11, 3};

        long sumOfA=0;
        long sumOfB=0;
        long sumOfC=0;

        int a = 0;             //set end of sub-array A
        int b = arr.length-1;  //set start of sub-array-C

        long maximum =0; // Minimum of sum of all subarrays should be maximum, 
                         // That will be sufficient to get the answer

        long answer=0;
        int answer_a=0;
        int answer_b=0;

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            sumOfB+=arr[i];
        }

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            long minimum = Math.min(sumOfA , Math.min(sumOfB,sumOfC));

            if(minimum>=maximum)
            {
                answer_a=a;
                answer_b=b;

                ArrayList<Long> list=new ArrayList<Long>();     //To calculate the answer
                list.add(sumOfA);
                list.add(sumOfB);
                list.add(sumOfC);
                Collections.sort(list);

                answer=Math.max(answer,list.get(0)+list.get(1));         //take minimum two elements
                maximum=minimum;
            } 

            if(sumOfB < sumOfC || sumOfB < sumOfA)
                break;

            if(a>=b)                //If both pointer passes to each other
                break;

            if(sumOfA == sumOfC)
            {
                if(arr[a]<arr[b])   //take minimum element
                {
                    sumOfA+=arr[a];
                    sumOfB-=arr[a];
                    a++;            //move a to next element 
                }
                else
                {
                    sumOfC+=arr[b];
                    sumOfB-=arr[b];
                    b--;            //move b to prev element
                }
            }
            else if(sumOfA > sumOfC)
            {
                sumOfC+=arr[b];
                sumOfB-=arr[b];
                b--;
            }
            else
            {
                sumOfA+=arr[a];
                sumOfB-=arr[a];
                a++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("a(exclsive) : "+answer_a);
        System.out.println("b(exclsive) : "+answer_b);
        System.out.println("Answer : "+answer);
    }
}
```

---

Answer for `[9, 12, 4, 7, 10, 2, 5, 8, 11, 3]` :

```
a(exclsive) : 3
b(exclsive) : 6
Answer : 46
```

---

Answer for `[6, 8, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6]` :

```
a(exclsive) : 2
b(exclsive) : 4
Answer : 26
```

Comment: You even took care of large inputs with your longs, very interesting approach!